# PySpark, Extract string from a column that matches a regex which itself has a placeholder value coming from another column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

So I have this issue extracting a string that matches a regex and in turn this regex has a placeholder which needs to be replaced by another column value

for example, the regex

```
regex = (
r"(?<EventCode>(?<=<EventId>)\d+(?=<\/EventId>)|(?<= SourceName Value_\D{1}_)\d+)"
)
```

and I have a table say like this:

| Message | SourceName |
| --- | --- |
| something SRC_INFO_S_3_DOOR | SRC_INFO |

I basically want to extract the Number 3 based on these 2 columns, In this case for every column, the regex would be different as the placeholder would be replaced by the value in the SourceName column and then using regexp_extract to fetch the 3.

But the problem is replacing the regex string with a value from the column

What I tried was create separate columns where in every row the regex string is replaced by the SourceName but then when using regexp_extract it requires a string for the regex and not the regex_column

The result expected would be a code column which has the value 3, for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use expr() with regex_replace to replace from column:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("DateDataFrame").getOrCreate()
data = [("replace me", "replace"), ("I love me", "love"), ("some text", "hello")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['c1', 'c2'])
df.show()
df.withColumn("c1", expr('regexp_replace(c1, c2, "")')).show()
```

Result

```
+----------+-------+
|        c1|     c2|
+----------+-------+
|replace me|replace|
| I love me|   love|
| some text|  hello|
+----------+-------+

+---------+-------+
|       c1|     c2|
+---------+-------+
|       me|replace|
|    I  me|   love|
|some text|  hello|
+---------+-------+
```

If you want to concatenate the column to replace with a regex, you can use concat like this:

```
df.withColumn("c1", expr('regexp_replace(c1, concat("regex_prefix" , c2, "regex_suffix"), "")')).show()
```

so in your case:

```
df.withColumn("c1", expr('regexp_replace(c1, concat("(?<EventCode>(?<=<EventId>)\d+(?=<\/EventId>)|(?<= " , c2, " Value_\D{1}_)\d+)"), "")')).show()
```

An alternative solution is to use udf, but this one is simpler and more effective.